# Computing an expression with limes and limit superior and floor-function

Tags: real-analysis, estimation

Let $2\leq e\leq r$. I am trying to compute or estimate (from above)
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left[(e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1}-((e+r)\cdot 2r+e+r+(e+r+1)\cdot r^2)^{c_{n,k}}\cdot (e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1-3c_{n,k}}\right],
$$
where $c_{n,k}=\lfloor\frac{2(n+k)-1}{3}\rfloor$.

The background is the following:

For the intervall $[n-k+1,n+k-1]$ around $0$, there are $a_{n,k}=(e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1}$ possibilities to put elements from the alphabet $\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,e,e+1,\ldots,e+r\right\}$. Now, there are special triples that cannot appear and I divide the interval $[n-k+1,n+k-1]$ into $c_{n,k}$ groups of three. For each group of three consecutive positions I have $(e+r)2r+e+r+(e+r+1)$ possibilities to choose such a forbidden triple. For the remaining $2(n+k)-1-3c_{n,k}$ positions, I have $e+r+1$ possibilities.

Of course, we have
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(a_{n,k})=2\log(e+r+1)
$$
and this is an upper bound in my computations.

But I would like to improve this by finding a smaller upper bound. That's why I am asking for the computation above.

Comment: Already, for every fixed $k$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(a_{n,k})=2\log(e+r+1).$$

Comment: @Did Yes, that's true. Does this observation help me to find a smaller upper bound than $2\log(e+r+1)$?

Comment: ?? If a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $\ell$, no value $\ell'<\ell$ is such that $x_n\leqslant\ell'$ for every $n$.

Comment: I mean if for my expression above, i.e. $\lim_{k\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log (a_{n,k}-\ldots)$ we can find a smaller upper bound than $2\log(e+r+1)$.

Comment: My first comment holds for $$a_{n,k}=(e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1}-((e+r)\cdot 2r+e+r+(e+r+1)\cdot r^2)^{c_{n,k}}\cdot (e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1-3c_{n,k}}.$$ I now realize you might have meant $$a_{n,k}=(e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1}$$ instead but the stronger result I mention also holds with "my" definition. (In retrospect, what do you think of the fact that $a_{n,k}$ is not even defined in your question?)

Comment: @Did Sorry, I meant $a_{n,k}:=(e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1}$. And I do not see why your argument holds for $b_{n,k}:=a_{n,k}-\ldots$.

Comment: Because $\lim\frac1n\log(x_n-y_n)=\log a$ when $\lim\frac1n\log x_n=\log a$, $\lim\frac1n\log y_n=\log b$ and $a>b>0$. So now you know what to do to check the assertion in my first comment.

Comment: Then I am wondering how I can improve the upper estimation. As mentioned, I have some configurations on $[-n-k+1,n+k-1]$, say $d_{n,k}$ configurations, that are not possible and so I can subtract them from $a_{n,k}=(e+r+1)^{2(n+k)-1}$, the total number of possibilities. Now, after the discussion, I do not really know how I can subtract $d_{n,k}$ from $a_{n,k}$ without getting again the same upper boundary.